# puppeteer: Is there a way to "restart" the browser such that it maintains storage and settings

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium, puppeteer

if I call `browser.close()` and re-run my setup logic all `browser.storage` is back to its default state, as well as the `browser.proxy.settings`. This doesn't happen if I just open and close chrome like normal.

I want to run some tests that go something like:

1) modify proxy settings

2) set a storage flag that says proxy should turn off when the browser starts

3) close the browser

4) open the browser again

5) assert that the storage key is how it was before closing and opening

6) check if the proxy settings have been turned off

Right now it seems like each launching of puppeteer the `chrome_user_data` is cleared. Is there a flag that I pass when launching that contains my previous data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must explicitly set the `userDataDir` on launch:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  userDataDir: './user-data-dir'
});
```

Then it should persist the data between runs.