# How do I kill all chromium processes?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I would like to kill all chromium processes created by puppeteer. I would usually properly close all the browsers from the puppeteer package itself but I am using a different package that uses puppeteer at the side. The problem is that the package does not properly close the chromium tab after it is not in use anymore and I want to manually kill the processes as it takes up a lot of memory if I wouldn't have done so.

I am trying to kill all the processes through the `fkill` package.

I have tried statments like,

```
fkill('chromium.exe', {force: true, silent: true, tree: true});

fkill('chromium-browser', {force: true, silent: true, tree: true});
```

I have additionally tried to use `browser.close` and `kill-tabs` to no avail.

Comment: *"but I am using a different package that uses puppeteer at the side."* is this package something you can't mention here (not available to public)?

Comment: The package is `youtube-videos-uploader` but unless you want to make a pull request to fix the issue, it will become a reoccurring issue. I have already made an issue to the packages GitHub [here](https://github.com/fawazahmed0/youtube-uploader/issues/109)

Comment: i dont plan to create a pull request. but it would be best if you could be specific on your problem so other people can help you better. afaik google has youtube api for [uploading stuffs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs). on a side note using puppeteer for uploading stuff may work for some time until google decide to mess with the ui later on ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ i personally wouldn't put my money on it.

Comment: Google has many limitations while uploading to youtube through their API (videos you upload can only be private). Using this package is kind of a bypass to upload videos publicly for my use. I know this would be a short-term fix for my problem but it is working for me for now. I have stated in the packages GitHub about my problem but they don't seem like they are actively updating their package. This is why I would like to kill all chromium processes manually as currently, the processes are taking up too much memory.

Comment: What code are you using to upload the videos? The problem appears to be that most of the library's funcs replace a single variable `browser` from different functions, so it might not leak if you do everything serially. If you're parallelizing, there's probably a quick fix you can make to clean things up in the library by using an object or map to keep track of each browser, adding a `finally` block or scoping it to a function. I think killing the parent process should reap the children, so you could potentially take control that way too.

Comment: Since this package uses puppeteer if you could use that puppeteer to get all processes and kill them

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72428263/how-to-clear-all-browsers-and-pages-started-by-puppeteer/72428976 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047783/puppeteer-is-there-a-way-to-restart-the-browser-such-that-it-maintains-storag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix to my problem was just giving up on `fkill` and using `Child Process` instead. Although the most plausible answer for a sure fix of this is by adding a `finally` to the library to keep track of each browser suggested by @ggorlen. Both methods work to fix my problem, thanks a lot!

```
cp.exec(`Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'chrome.exe' AND CommandLine LIKE '%--headless%'" | %{Stop-Process $_.ProcessId}`, {'shell':'powershell.exe'}, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
            })
```

Comment: how to do this on mac and linux? and you can possibly elaborate on what the command is doing and how to use it with puppeteer?

Comment: @AlessandroCatania `ps -aux | pgrep chrome | xargs kill -9 $1`

Answer (score 0):

Add `--single-process --no-zygote` on launch for avoiding multiple processes.
With `--single-process` you'll be able to run plugins and browser in the same process both.
With `--no-zygote` puppeteer **will not** fork children processes by father one.

When doing that if you simply `browser.disconnect` you will kill all processes then.

Comment: This still does not work to fix my problems. It somehow still leaves multiple processes open upon  `browser.disconnect`.

Comment: This will only prevent to create multiple processes ofc.
What you want to do is closing browser instance. To achieve that you should use [`browser.close`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v14.4.1&show=api-browserclose).

Comment: Yes even upon using `browser.close` it keeps the processes open.

Comment: Could you please provide us logs?

Comment: I have found a quick fix to my problem. Thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: @Flappy what was the fix you used?

Comment: The accepted answer is what I used.